# How to "sort" nested object array on MongoDB, so all items with a specific value are the firsts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this data and I want to sort it by two fields:
first by specific address (details.address), for example 'Tel Aviv'.
second by regular sort, by details.cost field.
here is my data:

```js
[{
    "_id": "123",
    "details": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "address": "Ramat Gan",
        "cost": "50"
    }, {
        "_id": "2",
        "address": "Tel Aviv",
        "cost": "30"
    }]
},
{
    "_id": "456",
    "details": [{
        "_id": "4",
        "address": "Modi'in",
        "cost": "40"
    }, {
        "_id": "5",
        "address": "Tel Aviv",
        "cost": "20"
    }]
}
]
```

and I want to get this data after the two sorting:

```js
[{
    "_id": "456",
    "details": [{
        "_id": "5",
        "address": "Tel Aviv",
        "cost": "20"
    }, {
        "_id": "4",
        "address": "Modi'in",
        "cost": "40"
    }, {
        "_id": "123",
        "details": [{
            "_id": "2",
            "address": "Tel Aviv",
            "cost": "30"
        }, {
            "_id": "1",
            "address": "Ramat Gan",
            "cost": "50"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

actually, I want to sort by my specific value address' (in this case - 'Tel Aviv') cost

Comment: Could you show us the code that gives you this data?

Comment: db.<collectionName>.insertMany(
[{
    "_id": "123",
    "details": [{
        "_id": "1",
        "address": "Ramat Gan",
        "cost": "50"
    }, {
        "_id": "2",
        "address": "Tel Aviv",
        "cost": "30"
    }]
},
{
    "_id": "456",
    "details": [{
        "_id": "4",
        "address": "Modi'in",
        "cost": "40"
    }, {
        "_id": "5",
        "address": "Tel Aviv",
        "cost": "20"
    }]
}
])

Comment: Is it enough for you, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want both splitting and sorting by cost you can expand @BuzzMoschetti's solution `$group` part to use `$cond`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$details"},
  {$sort: {"details.cost": 1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      top: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [{$eq: ["$details.address", "Tel Aviv"]}, "$details", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      bottom: {
        $push: {
          $cond: [{$ne: ["$details.address", "Tel Aviv"]}, "$details", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {details: {$concatArrays: ["$top", "$bottom"]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example both](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9sYWLgS_PpK)

In case you to just order by specific address first:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      top: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$details",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.address", "Tel Aviv"]}
        }
      },
      bottom: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$details",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$ne: ["$$item.address", "Tel Aviv"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      details: {$concatArrays: ["$top", "$bottom"]}
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example top-city](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9dBDLNV-Azh)

Comment: Clever use of `$$REMOVE` here to "not push" something.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:  `$unwind` then re-`$group`.  When sorting arrays of things across document boundaries you pretty much have no choice but to use `$unwind` to let `$sort` work properly.

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$details'}
    ,{$sort: {'details.address':-1,'details.cost':1}}

    // Rebuild the original doc; $push will *preserve* the sorted
    // order of address+cost following from the stage above:
    ,{$group: {_id:'$_id', details: {$push: '$details'}}}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Buzz Moschetti.
but I don't want to sort my address ascending or descending.
I only want to top specific value for address, 
for example, I want to see all the records of 'Tel Aviv's at the top of their object, as like as the example.
Do you know hoe can I do it?

Comment: I am confused; the answer matches your indicated target output.    Can you edit the output in the question to make this "top specific value for address" more clear?   What is a "top specific value"?

Comment: Is it more clear?
I want to see all the objects with the specific value field as the firsts in their array.